# Insert data into table with values inside quotes of another select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert data into multiple columns of a table with specific values. However one varchar column will have its data value coming from another table select statement placed inside a quotes.

I need it placed inside without having the sub select statement interpreted as part of the string. Below is my query;

```
INSERT INTO Table1
            (column1,
             column2,
             column3,
             column4)
VALUES     (484640,
            4,
            1,
            '<HTML><Head></Head><Body><a href="cgroup-histstatus.aspx?Staging_PKID=(select distinct column_1 from Table_2)">Upload results</a></Body></HTML>')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently your `select` query will be just treated like a string since it is enclosed within single quotes. The query will be inserted into the column, not the result.

Here is the correct way:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
            (column1,
             column2,
             column3,
             column4)
SELECT DISTINCT 484640,
                4,
                1,
                '<HTML><Head></Head><Body><a href="cgroup-histstatus.aspx?Staging_PKID='
                + cast(column_1 as varchar(50))
                + '">Upload results</a></Body></HTML>'
FROM   Table_2
```

If you want the values from `column_1` to be enclosed within single quotes then replace `'+ column_1 +'` with `'''+ column_1 +'''`.

This works even when `select` query returns more than one record.

Comment: Mmm, sweet sweet SQL injection attack.

Comment: the data on the column_1 of table_2 is bigint while the column being inserted into is varchar. I am getting error converting data type. what am i missing?

Comment: @Dren - Then you need to explicitly convert to `varchar` before concatenating with string

Comment: @DanBron - Am DB guy, dont have much idea about HTML. But I couldn't find any possibility of sql injection here. We are not executing any query based on user input. Can you expand on it ?

Comment: @Prdp Do you know where the data in "column_1" came from? Are you *super* sure?

Comment: @DanBron - As I said earlier, I dont know HTML tags. By concatenating `BIGINT` data with HTML tags I don't know the possibility of sql injection so please explain it so that it will be useful to someone/OP

Comment: @Prdp should i use convert(int[column_1]) or convert(varchar,column_1)?

Comment: @Dren - I have already updated my answer. If you want to use `CONVERT` function then `convert(varchar(50),column_1)`. Always mention the length of `varchar` in `Convert` or `CAST` function. By default it will be f length `30`

Comment: @Prdp yeah just saw it after i add the comment. it worked like how i wanted it.. many thanks.

Comment: @Dren - Dan Bron was mentioning about `SQL INJECTION` check that as well. Am not sure about HTML tags

Comment: @Prdp if the url return would be like below would it be a security issue?
https://website.com/cgroup-histstatus.aspx?Staging_PKID=24639